# Write data to influxDB cloud with MicroPython

Tags: influxdb, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

i want to write some sensor data with my raspberry pico w to my influxDB cloud.
I saw there is a way to manage that by using the influxDB client with python. As far as I know there is no way doing that withe the MicroPython/PicoW combination right?

But is there another way to get it going maybe through http requests or something?

Comment: It looks as if [this project](https://github.com/costastf/temperature_sensor_influx) used MicroPython to write to InfluxDB, so you could start by looking there. It might be out of date though - I don't have any experience with InfluxDB.

Answer (score 0):

You can write to the InfluxDB cloud using MicroPython like this.

First import the `urequest` module and then follow the code below. In the following example, I am writing to the measurement "measurement1" and I have a "location" tag and "temperature" and "humidity" fields.

```
import urequests

url = "https://us-east-1-1.aws.cloud2.influxdata.com/api/v2/write?org={YOUR-ORG-NAME}&bucket={YOUR-BUCKET-NAME}&precision=ns"

headers = {
        "Authorization": "Token {YOUR-TOKEN}",
        "Content-Type": "text/plain; charset=utf-8",
        "Accept": "application/json"
}

data = f"measurement1,location={location} temperature={temperature},humidity={humidity}"
```

Replace the following placeholders with your values,

- {YOUR-ORG-NAME}
- {YOUR-BUCKET-NAME}
- {YOUR-TOKEN}
- {location} - ensure this value has no spaces
- {temperature}
- {humidity}

And post to the URL like this,

```
response = urequests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
    
if response.status_code == 204:
    print("Data posted successfully")
else:
    print("Failed to post data")
    print("Status Code:", response.status_code)
    print("Response:", response.text)
    response.close()
```

I hope this helps. Thank you!